# Combine two sql select queries (in postgres) with LIMIT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, limit, union

I've got a table and I want a query that returns the last 10 records created plus the record who's id is x.

I'm trying to do -

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_productimage
ORDER BY date_modified
LIMIT 10
UNION
SELECT * FROM catalog_productimage
WHERE id=5;
```

But it doesn't look like I can put `LIMIT` in there before `UNION`. I've tried adding another column and using it for sorting -

```
SELECT id, date_modified, IF(false, 1, 0) as priority FROM catalog_productimage
UNION
SELECT, id, date_modified, IF(true, 1, 0) as priority FROM catalog_productimage
WHERE id=5
ORDER BY priority, date_modified
LIMIT 10;
```

but I'm not making much progress..

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Just checked that this will work:

```
(SELECT * FROM catalog_productimage
ORDER BY date_modified
LIMIT 10)
UNION
SELECT * FROM catalog_productimage
WHERE id=5;
```

Comment: Round brackets are required because `UNION` is actually a part of select statement and select statement syntax is such that `LIMIT` must come after `UNION`. So you need to explicitly end first expression. Also because of this syntax you to use `LIMIT` at the end of union. This way `LIMIT` would be applied to outcome of the union. See [Select documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) for more details.

Comment: So if we had 3 untions to do, would this require a new set of paranthesis for each untion?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you records from 10th to 20th and should get you started.i will reply back with SQLfiddle

```
SELECT *  
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY cat_id) cat_row_no, a.* FROM catalog_productimage a where x=5)  
 WHERE cat_row_no > 10 and cat_row_no <20
```